# How do you "ungroup" an image in PowerPoint using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint file with a slide with an image (wmf/emp file) in it and I want to "ungroup" the image elements in it using VBA.

I need to ask PowerPoint twice to do it - but then it does.

Can it be done using VBA? and if so, how?

Comment: Was the object 'Group'ed in the first place? Are you saying there's more than one WMF 'Group'ed together? If the object is just one lone WMF, isn't that impervious to being deconstructed into individual lines without writing directly to the GDI?

Comment: Power point asks if to turn the object into a Microsoft object, I agree - and it ungroups it.

Comment: Understandably I just don't have the wherewithal to duplicate your problem without knowing more. I assume you have the VBA editor ready (a Developer tab on your ribbon)? If so, have you tried the routine you describe while Record Macro is running? Maybe Record Macro will pick up the actions you're doing and automatically translate them into code to start with.  If it does, and your reprocessing that into a Subroutine doesn't solve the problem, then...having the Sub run the snip twice will.  (That's all, of course, predicated upon even retrieving something useful from the Record session.)

Comment: Hello. I want to ask you something about how to ungroup some shapes. For my job, I have 239 slides and then for every slide I have to press right click and the press "ungroup". Is there any macro which ungroup all the slides only once? I received some help here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34432550/any-vba-code-to-align-the-picture-from-powerpoint, but this code doesnt't work very well because copies all the picures from all the slides and put together in a slide which I pick up with the mouse. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly simple - from the help file:

> This example ungroups any grouped
>   shapes and disassembles any pictures
>   or OLE objects on myDocument.
>
> ```
> Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
> For Each s In myDocument.Shapes
>     s.Ungroup
> Next
> ```

You may need to do some error checking if it can't be ungrouped, like a JPG, and some type checking (i.e. `If s.Type = msoPicture...`)

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to the question but...

The single best way to figure out how to automate office applications with VBA is to [record a macro and then look at the code that gets spit out](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=402032).

Comment: Thanks - I'll remember that for next time.