# Any VBA code to align the picture from PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint document with 239 slides. I have to align the picture from every slide making the following two steps:

**1.** Right click and select *Edit Picture*

**2.** Then Press *YES*

[image]

[image]

**My question:** Is there any macro (vba code) to do all this job automatically?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft stores complex vector objects in WMF or EMF formats and in order to edit them one needs to convert them to native MSO drawing objects (vectors). The process to do this is to ungroup them and this code will do it for your entire presentation:

```
Option Explicit

' ===================================================================
' Purpose : Loop through each shape of each slide in a presentation
'           and ungroup and WMF files, thereby converting them to
'           MSO drawing objects that can be edited.
' Author  : Jamie at YOUpresent Ltd. http://youpresent.co.uk/
' ===================================================================
Sub ConvertAllMetafilePicturestoGroups()
  Dim oSld As Slide
  Dim oShp As Shape
  For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
      On Error Resume Next ' In case picture is a bitmap and not a WMF vector
      If oShp.Type = msoPicture Then oShp.Ungroup
      On Error GoTo 0
    Next
  Next
  ' Clean up
  Set oShp = Nothing: Set oSld = Nothing
End Sub
```

You can ungroup a second time if you want/need to.

Comment: One question, please. The code is working but why does this code copy all the graphs from the slides and put its in one slide which I pressed click? thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand luli. The code shouldn't be copying anything. It just loops through all shapes of all slides and tries to ungroup any that are of type "picture". How are you calling the sub?